# What to change into GBP?

Tags: banking, foreign-exchange, usd-us-dollar, eur-euro, gbp-british-pound

I'll be in Scotland for one day and I will need to buy ticket for the bus. 
I have 
American Visa travel credit card, 
american debit card, 
euro, 
and dollars. 
Which one is better to use to change euro/dollars into £?
Thanks

Comment: Can you define "better?" Is it in terms of price, convenience, something else? Your question is a bit broad at this point.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking how much and how to change the price of a single bus ticket from EUR/USD into GBP?

Comment: Which bus?  Are you sure they don't take Euros?

Comment: Are you looking to minimize exchange fees? Assuming you can just use the travel card, I don't see any need to do any explicit currency exchange.

Comment: It's just a complete nonstarter thinking about the cash. You can't "precisely" change £4.35 - it's just a nonstarter.  Simply use a card.

Answer (score 1):

The cards will definitely be better than the cash.

Simply check the two cards you have, and compare the fees for the two on international transactions - you'll have your answer.

Just forget about changing cash.

And have a Whisky for us !

Comment: Yes, for one day, KISS and use the card...

Comment: For sure.  it's apparently *one transaction*, for goodness sake.